# Permission to repo denied to github-actions for PR coming from a Fork only

Tags: github, github-actions

We have a Github action that can change files(like running fmt) on PR and it works fine on local PR, but when the PR comes from a FORK, it fails with the error that "Permission to repo denied to github-actions[bot]".

Digging a bit seems to indicate that PR coming from FORKS have a GITHUB_TOKEN set to "read" only, no matter what we set in the yml "permissions" section or in the repo Github Actions setting.

But in the doc that mention this, I see no solution on how to actually allow it..?

Any solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a security measure taken by github to prevent arbitrary forks from running actions on your repository.

If you want pull requests to have write permissions **and to run on the target repository**, you can use `target: pull_request_target`.

You can find information on this here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request_target

> For workflows that are triggered by the pull_request_target event, the GITHUB_TOKEN is granted read/write repository permission unless the permissions key is specified and the workflow can access secrets, even when it is triggered from a fork.

Comment: Thanks, that page explains it "almost" clearly. :P. But I get the gist of it, and it makes sense.  The proposed solution seems to work too(did a simple test and it passed), thanks :)